# Dell Poweredge 710 Server amber flashing light

Tags: dell-poweredge, raid0

I have Dell PowerEdge R710 with PERC 6i and I am trying to install HP 512 HB SSD in RAID 0 and for some reason, it is constantly blinking flashing amber instead of green.
I am running Hyper-V on Windows server 2016.
Drive shows up fine and seems to be working.
SSD is a brand new SSD.

I am also running other raid configurations on same server (one is raid 0 with two 1tb 3.5" SATA and the other one is RAID 1 with 500GB SAS hard drives)

Can someone please assist me in figuring out what an issue might be. Does my server really support SATA SSDs?

Here are my Raid Configurations for SSD
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

My bios also seems to be updated as seen below:
[image]

Here is the error I see on LCD screen

> E1810 Hard drive 4 fault. Review & clear SEL

Thanks

Comment: The amber light is from the drive trays for those ssd ? Other trays ? Or is it the amber light from the front ? If the front - check if both your PSUs are hooked up. If its the drive trays, go into the Raid GUI and check there ...  SATA SSDs are fine on my machine. The server may complain about non dell branded drives  but will still use them ..

Comment: Light is from drive tray with an ssd. Other trays with 3.5" sata or sas drives are all green. I looked into raid configuration and it looks good as far as drive is in a bay. As soon as I remove the drive and re-insert it, it is recognized as foreign. I tried with and without initialization of my raid pool. It is still flashing amber constantly.

Comment: Noted. 1. Check iDRAC  for any issues 2. U may try updating all the firmware ( especially Raid Card )  . 3. Could u post some screenshots of your ssd raid here ? 4. If all fails, a black marker will provide some peace of mind ...

Comment: I added pictures of my Virtual Disk configuration. My bios also seem to be updated. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Hi ... For E1810 Hard drive 4 fault. Review & clear SEL , Pls goto your iDRAC and clear the logs ( System Event Log ). Power OFF the box and reseat the HDrive. Power ON and see if the error re-appears.

Comment: Next , the pics -> Raid Status is Optimal. Thats good. Pls expand 'Physical Disks' snd add that pic. I will check back later.